# Is there a thing such as "packaged web app"?

Tags: javascript, browser, packaging

Let's say I have a HTML/JS application, which is on a website and runs without any server-side component (except the web server, of course). So it's basically just a bunch of `.html`, `.css` and `.js` files (and some others, like images or SQLite databases)

Someday, an user comes to me to ask me if I can make an offline version, so they can access the app when they are offline.
My first reaction would be to provide them all the files of the app in a `.zip` file or something, but this is not really good: it's not "clear" to an average user, and the files and code are apparent (which could be "dangerous" if the user edits or deletes them by accident).

So I was wondering: is there a kind of format that would makes me able to store the files of the app in a packaged file?
The file would be something like a `.zip` file, but when you click to the file, instead of opening up the archive, it opens the `/index.html` (or similar) which is inside.

So for the user, it would be similar to open an `.exe` or a single `.html` file, but still that's not a native app, as that's still a browser app.

Given that I know about:

- Apache Cordova; but most of the time, I just use the browser functions, and I don't have a need to use advanced native functionalities;
- UWP and PWA, but I don't know if it's exactly what I want (I imagine it as a mix of website and mobile app, but I'm surely wrong);
- Open Web App (a standard from Mozilla), but based on what I've read about it, it seems deprecated and not used anymore. Plus, I don't really look forward to "certify" my app... I just want to package some files.

Comment: You should be able to open your .html pages inside Google Chrome and it will work out of the box? Provided it's just .html, .css and .js and all of the files are available within the archive

Comment: I'm not sure there is a standard cross-browser format, but you could provide the app as a Chrome Web Application for Chrome for example.

Comment: @sjahan Chrome Apps are being deprecated as of now and they are supported only in Chrome OS from here on. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Comment: @AK47 Yeah of course. But that's the point of my post: I wonder if there is something that, instead of having a bunch of html/css/js files, we would have them all encapsulated in a single file, which would make it easier for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

PWA I don't think is a solution to your problem as you wont be able to redistribute the code as an executable package.

UWP would be too Windows specific and might make you lose the platform independence that you already have since you are using plain HTML and JS, plus from what I understand you would need to distribute the app on Windows Store.

I believe packaging as an Electron app would be the best solution as you can provide executable files that can be executed in almost all platforms.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to say, but I used Electron for some apps (I mistaken it with Cordova in my post...). The thing is Electron provides a full engine and adds its APIs, which I don't really need for some apps, as they were initially not native. The thing I'm really searching for is something that would open up in the user's regular browser, so it won't take all the space needed by Electron (plus, Electron gave me some problems, for example I couldn't use `prompt()` )

Answer (score 0):

[Electron](https://electronjs.org/) would be the best solution for you. I had a client that first wanted to run app on php server and eventually they figured out they need it as a desktop app. It was easy to rewrite php stuff to node and package as Electron app. You have access to everything files, system etc. so you can do more if needed.

Another solution would be to just inline everything into a single html file.